# Server Error 404 is returned when trying to get an authorization code from live.com

Tags: oauth-2.0

We have two applications which use OAuth2 authentication to get access to Hotmail.
The first application works fine. But in the second application we have an error after entering login/password:

> Server Error
>
> 404 - File or directory not found.
>
> The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

URLs and code used to show these URLs are identical in both application:

```
url = "https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.live.com%2Foauth20_desktop.srf&scope=wl.imap+wl.offline_access+wl.emails&client_id=REAL-CLIENT-ID"
self.browser.load(QUrl(url))
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how can fix it. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's weird but this issue was fixed by adding:

```
QCoreApplication.setOrganizationName("anOrganizationName")
QCoreApplication.setOrganizationDomain("anOrganizationDomain")
QCoreApplication.setApplicationName("anApplicationName")
```

Perhaps it would be enough one of these string to fix issue. I didn't check it.